# Do I have to do anything in a destructor to free non-pointer member variables?

Tags: c++, class, instance, destructor, member

If I have something like

```
class Foo { ... }

class UsesFoo {
private:
    Foo foo;
public:
    UsesFoo() : foo(1, 2, 3) { }
}
```

Then as I understand it, when I construct a `UsesFoo` (be it `UsesFoo *myMan = new UsesFoo();` or `UsesFoo myMan;`), it creates a `Foo` object as if by calling `Foo(1, 2, 3)`. When `UsesFoo` gets destroyed (be it by `delete myMan;` or by going out of scope), the `Foo` inside will also be destructed.

If I provide the following destructor, will the `Foo` still be destructed?

```
~UsesFoo() { }
```

If not, then what do I have to do to destruct `Foo`? In other words, what are the semantics of how non-pointer member variables that are instances of classes are destructed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I provide the following destructor, will the `Foo` still be destructed?

**Yes**. Quoth the standard,

> After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic objects allocated within the body, a
>   destructor for class `X` calls the destructors for `X`’s direct non-variant non-static data members, the destructors
>   for `X`’s direct base classes and, if `X` is the type of the most derived class (12.6.2), its destructor calls the
>   destructors for `X`’s virtual base classes.

(C++11, §12.4/8)

Comment: Nice, a quote from the standard =). How far back before C++11 does this apply?

Comment: @Claudiu To the beginning of time itself.

Comment: @Claudiu well, it's §12.4/6 in C++03. But I'm inclined to agree with Dave's comment.

Comment: @Dave: Hah. I figured as much, just wanted to make sure.